# Сделать проверку массива с помощью функции

Tags: c++, массивы, visual-c++

II. Даны натуральное число n (n≥2) и действительный квадрат¬ный массив размера nn. Построить последовательность b1, b2, ..., bn  из нулей  и единиц, в которой  bi = 1 тогда и только тогда, когда элементы i-й строки матрицы образуют возрастающую последовательность.

---

Код работает, но нужно чтобы проверка происходила с помощью функции. Помогите, а то уже голова кипит

---

```
int main() {
int n;
int flag;
double** arr;
double* b;
cout << "Enter array size: ";
cin >> n;
cout << endl;
arr = new double* [n];
b = new double[n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    arr[i] = new double[n];

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        cout << "Enter " << "[" << i + 1 << "][" << j + 1 <<
            "] element of massive >> ";
        cin >> arr[i][j];
    }
}

cout << endl << "Your array:" << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        cout << setw(4) << arr[i][j];
    }

    cout << endl << endl;
}

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    flag = 1;

    for (int j = 0; j < n - 1 && flag == 1; j++)
        if (arr[i][j + 1] <= arr[i][j]) flag = 0;

    b[i] = flag;
}

cout << endl << "The answer is: ";

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout << b[i] << ' ';
}
cout << endl;
delete[] b;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    delete[] arr[i];
}

delete[]arr;
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция

```
int isGrowing(double *row, int cols){
    int flag=1;
    for (int i=0; i<cols-1 && flag==1; i++){
        if (row[i]>row[i+1]) flag=0;
    }

    return flag;
}
```

Использование

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    b[i] = isGrowing(arr[i], n);
}
```

Comment: боже, мой спаситель. Благодарю

Comment: Ну, я бы использовал `bool` - все-таки С++, убрал `&& flag==1`, а вместо `if (row[i]>row[i+1]) flag=0;` - написал бы `if (row[i]>row[i+1]) return false;` - какой смысл проверять на каждой итерации `flag`?

Comment: @Harry вы не обратили внимания на условие окончания цикла. А две точки выхода в такой простой функции это моветон.

Comment: Обратил. Именно о нем и говорю - проверять в худшем случае N раз условие - вот моветон, а цепляться за одну тчоку выхода - догматизм. :) А если уж и делать одну точку выхода - то можно использовать оператор `break`. Или это тоже моветон?

Comment: @Harry Проверка условия O(1) имеет константную сложность, что не влияет на скорость работы, так как в худшем случае ваш способ дает столько же сравнений. А вот в среднем сравнений будет n/2. Я отчетливо написал, что две точки выхода в такой примитивной задаче бессмысленны и сильно затрудняют чтение кода.

Comment: Достучаться к некоторым я бессилен, впрочем, оно и к лучшему - задание учебное, препод ждет код с огрехами, он его и получит. Наверное, вы правы :)

Comment: @Harry я же вам написал, что сложность проверки что такого условия `i<cols-1`, что такого `i<cols-1 && flag==1` одинакова. И предложенная вами правка ничего не добавит. Понятно, что если бы в условии проверка зависела от количества элементов массива (функция некая например), то тогда имело бы смысл исправлять. Вы же предлагаете обфускацию кода без существенных обоснований и прироста производительности.